# Concat two dataframe where one dataframe is subset of other

Tags: pandas

I have two data frames

DF1

```
 x y z   
 0 0 0  
 1 1 1  
 2 2 2  
 3 3 3  
 4 4 4  
 5 5 5
```

DF2

```
 x y z    
 1 1 10   
 4 4 20
```

I want to concat these two data frame which updates data frame 1

Result should be

```
 x y z   
 0 0 0  
 1 1 10  
 2 2 2  
 3 3 3  
 4 4 20  
 5 5 5
```

I use:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], sort=False).drop_duplicates(['x'],keep='last')
```

What I get

```
 x y z   
 0 0 0  
 2 2 2  
 3 3 3  
 5 5 5  
 1 Nan 10  
 4 Nan 20
```

Is there any way to get this using pandas built in methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need left `merge` and `ffill` and `drop` unwanted columns

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['x','y'], how='left', suffixes=['_1','']).ffill(1).drop('z_1',1).astype(int)

Out[104]:
   x  y   z
0  0  0   0
1  1  1  10
2  2  2   2
3  3  3   3
4  4  4  20
5  5  5   5
```